# Can DisplayPort carry USB?

Tags: usb, displayport

Are there any plans in current or future DisplayPort implementations to carry USB?

I'm thinking that you could have your keyboard/mouse plugged into your monitor and then two DisplayPort inputs. The input would get routed over DisplayPort and your monitor would act as a keyboard-mouse switch.

Comment: @oachimSauer: You put a bounty on this post that asks "Can DisplayPort carry USB", where the answer is "No". However, the accepted answer is for USB carrying DisplayPort, where the answer is "Yes". Now which is it?

Comment: @harrymc: I'm interested if there's any change about carrying USB signals over physical DP cables/connectors. I'm aware that many DP connections are now done via USB Type-C alternate mode (which can then also carry "normal USB"), but I'm curious about the theoretical possibility mentioned in the accepted answer ever coming to become practically possible.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> **Note:** It is now 2020, and this answer was written in 2011. At the time, the OP was probably referring to DisplayPort carried over the standard DisplayPort connector.
>
> Nowadays, DisplayPort signals can be carried over USB Type-C connectors, with the added benefit of being able to transmit USB data, too. The answer is about USB being carried over the standard DisplayPort connector, which is possible in theory, but not really available in practice.

---

In principle it *can*. The feature is called **USB over AUX**, since the DisplayPort v1.2 Standard specifies this in its Link Layer.

You'll find information in the [DisplayPort 1.2 press release](http://www.displayport.org/pr/vesa%C2%AE-introduces-displayport%E2%84%A2-v1-2-the-most-comprehensive-and-innovative-display-interface-available/):

> Another new feature is the ability to support high-speed, bi-directional data transfer, allowing USB 2.0 or Ethernet data to be carried within a standard DisplayPort cable. For DisplayPort v1.2, the maximum data rate of this “AUX” channel has been increased from 1 Mbps (Mega-bit-per-second) to 720 Mbps, providing suitable bandwidth for USB 2.0.  The DisplayPort cable can therefore support USB data to/from the display to support Display USB functions, in addition to sending the video and audio information. Standard Ethernet can also be transported in the DisplayPort cable.

Also, see this [presentation](http://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ICCE-Presentation-on-VESA-DisplayPort.pdf) from VESA's Craig Wiley at the IEEE International Conference on Consumer Electronics for a relevant quote:

> Fast AUX mode can be used for USB 2.0 data to support USB hub in Display
> (cable consolidation)

[image]

I don't know of any current DisplayPort v1.2 enabled devices, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: The only DisplayPort 1.2 devices I'm aware of, period, is the current Apple Cinema Display and any current Macs with a Thunderbolt port.  (Thunderbolt supports DP1.2) I don't know if the Cinema Display supports USB specifically, though, or even if it has USB ports.

Comment: @Shinrai I think the Cinema displays have USB ports, but they are probably separate from the DP connection.

Comment: It's been 5 years since this was answered. Are there any real implementations today?

Comment: @DonGar I don't know, honestly. One could place a bounty on this question to find out. Quickly doing a web search I found this: http://www.icron.com/ces/documents/USB-over-DisplayPort-Technology-Demonstration-Diagram.pdf

Comment: @DonGar it would seem USB-C is set to become the single cable to end all others. Defying common sense, the C cable has higher throughput than DP1.2. http://semiaccurate.com/2014/09/22/vesa-puts-displayport1-3-usb-c/ As an EE myself, this is the 1st time I've even been excited about a cable and/or its standard.

Comment: Indeed, a USB C cable can carry two lanes of DisplayPort traffic and USB 3.1 signals using the other two HSLs or it can carry four lanes of DP traffic and still have USB 2.0 next to it and with USB 4 it will be able to carry any mix of DP, PCIe and USB up to a 40gb/s combined speed.

Answer (score 11):

**2021 update**

In answer to the bounty question of Joachim Sauer for there's any change about
carrying USB signals over physical DP cables/connectors: There hasn't been
any change and don't expect one any time soon (or ever). Here is why.

The DisplayPort cable signals specify one lane for auxiliary traffic, as follows:

[image]

This auxiliary lane is described by
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Auxiliary_channel):

> **Auxiliary channel**
>
> The DisplayPort AUX channel is a half-duplex bidirectional data
> channel used for miscellaneous additional data beyond video and audio
> (such as I2C or CEC commands) at the device manufacturer's
> discretion. AUX signals are transmitted across a dedicated set of
> twisted-pair wires. DisplayPort 1.0 specified Manchester encoding with
> a 2 Mbaud signal rate (1 Mbit/s data rate). DisplayPort 1.2
> introduced a second transmission mode called FAUX (Fast AUX), which
> operates at 720 Mbaud with 8b/10b encoding (576 Mbit/s data
> rate). This can be used to implement additional transport
> protocols such as **USB 2.0 (480 Mbit/s)** without the need for an
> additional cable, but **has seen little practical use as of 2018**.

The DisplayPort 1.2 aux lane only has enough bandwidth to accommodate one USB 2.0,
so any USB 3.0 hub would need to connect through a dedicated cable.
In practice the Aux lane is rarely used for anything beyond basic management
commands for the display and such. Special functions like Ethernet or USB
would need support from the graphics card and drivers in order to route data
through the GPU's outputs, so are not practical.

There have also been developments since the DisplayPort specification was designed,
with the arrival of USB 3.0 that starts at 5 Gbps,
and with the introduction of USB Type-C with DisplayPort Alt Mode.

In view of these developments, the DisplayPort Aux channel feature is effectively
obsolete. I doubt that it will ever see a move from the industry to implement it.
Instead, we have seen the opposite, DisplayPort carried through USB ports.

Comment: so even with a usb-c - display port cable (usb-c on one end and displayport on the other) it wouldn't be possible to carry say mouse and keyboard plugged into the monitor back to laptop? that's a bummer i was hoping to use that with a phone (which has a desktop mode)