# USB over DisplayPort

Tags: usb, displayport

I know that DisplayPort (DP) can handle video, audio and other data (aux channel). Todays monitors does not support data over DP besides it has USB ports. I want to connect USB mouse to monitor and transfer over DP to PC (not over USB hub) plus audio and video. Is it possible with adapters, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [DisplayPort Specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Specifications), yes. The video card would need to support it, *and* the monitor would have to support it. You will still need the extra USB cable to hook it up to your monitor if you want to use its USB ports

Comment: Interesting. This post is saying: "Of course it can. The feature is called USB over AUX". http://superuser.com/questions/363649/can-displayport-carry-usb